# How can i create a way for a animation to have root motion for npc

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Ok I have a npc script, and I have a walking animation for a character, right now the character just slides to the player while playing the animation, and it does not move with each step that the rig is taking, and just doing the animation in place, while it is sliding to the character, how can i make it so it will move with each step, and also, it is a animation that would make a character take 2 steps, pause, take 2 more steps, so just lining up the timing would not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to set the walk animation to loop. Set the trigger/bool in AnimatorController when the character is moving and set it to false it isn't moving.